# Configurable fileName in RollingRandomAccessFile log4j2.xml

Tags: java, maven, war, log4j2

In maven war deployment, is it possible to make log4j2.xml fileName as configurable. Following is my application structure.

[image]

Currently the paths are hardcoded in the log4j2.xml file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Lookups in the file name that will be evaluated when the configuration is processed. So you can create a file name like “${sys:LOG_DIR:-logs}/app.log”.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where we will configure the LOG_DIR ?. Am using a linux system. I tried with LOG_DIR='/home/prepaid/LOGS/RRE/'
export LOG_DIR. But every time its taking the default path.

Comment: In my example LOG_DIR is a Java System Property. You would specify that as -DLOG_DIR="/home/prepaid/LOGS/RRE" on the command line. If you want to set an environment variable then use ${env:LOG_DIR:-logs}/lapp.log" See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html for other Lookups you could use.